# Perguntas com títulos diferentes mas com contexto e problemas iguais

Tags: debate, perguntas, título

Hoje fazendo uma busca me deparei com essas duas Perguntas:

- **[Erro e duvidas sql FireBird](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286909/erro-e-duvidas-sql-firebird)**
- **[Problema com SQL no Firebird](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286885/problema-com-sql-no-firebird)**

Elas têm os títulos bem diferentes mas o conteúdo é o mesmo. Como Proceder nesses casos?

Comment: Neste e em casos semelhantes, sempre que a resposta a ambas for a mesma, deve considerar a segunda como duplicata da primeira.

Comment: sinalize como duplicata. Sinalizar -> deveria ser fechada -> Duplicata de ...

Comment: Agora que percebi, a primeira pergunta foi editada depois que a resposta foi feita, para corrigir um problema de digitação. :|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minha experiencia como editor é que poucas vezes o título reflete a essência do problema apresentado na pergunta.

A principal caracteristica positiva das duplicatas é que vão criando referencias para um mesmo problema descrito de várias formas.

Como regra geral, se a resposta que você daria na Pergunta 1 é a mesma que daria na Pergunta 2, então deveria votar para fechar como duplicata.

Se a pergunta que vai ser usada como fonte para fechar outras como duplicata tiver um título ruim como os mostrados aqui, o ideal é editar para algo mais orgânico e definitivo.

Comment: `poucas vezes o título reflete a essência do problema apresentado na pergunta.` Isso é verdade e é por isso que não podemos ter coisas boas.